# Cumulating value of current row + sum of previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

How would you do to transform a Column in a table from this:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
2           a
3           b
4           c
5           d
1           a
```

to this:

```
ColumnA          ColumnB
3                 a
6(=3+3)           b   
10(=4+3+3)        c   
15(=5+4+3+3)      d
```

I'm interested to see esp. what method you would pick.

Answer (score 28):

Like this:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
   SELECT ColumnB, SUM(ColumnA) asum 
   FROM @t 
   gROUP BY ColumnB

), cteRanked AS
(
   SELECT asum, ColumnB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnB) rownum
   FROM cte
) 
SELECT (SELECT SUM(asum) FROM cteRanked c2 WHERE c2.rownum <= c1.rownum),
  ColumnB
FROM cteRanked c1;
```

This should give you:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
3             a
6             b
10            c
15            d
```

---

### Here is [a live demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81416/cumulative-sum-with-group-by)

Answer (score 9):

I'd generally avoid trying to do so, but the following matches what you've asked for:

```
declare @T table (ColumnA int,ColumnB char(1))
insert into @T(ColumnA,ColumnB) values
(2    ,       'a'),
(3   ,        'b'),
(4  ,         'c'),
(5 ,          'd'),
(1,           'a')

;With Bs as (
    select distinct ColumnB from @T
)
select
    SUM(t.ColumnA),b.ColumnB
from
    Bs b
        inner join
    @T t
        on
            b.ColumnB >= t.ColumnB
group by
    b.ColumnB
```

Result:

```
            ColumnB
----------- -------
3           a
6           b
10          c
15          d
```

For small data sets, this will be fine. But for larger data sets, note that the last row of the table relies on obtaining the `SUM` over the entire contents of the original table.

Answer (score 7):

Try the below script,

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ColumnA INT, ColumnB VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
    (2, 'a'),
    (3, 'b'),
    (4, 'c'),
    (5, 'd'),
    (1, 'a');

SELECT  SUM(ColumnA) OVER(ORDER BY ColumnB) AS ColumnA,ColumnB
FROM    (   SELECT  SUM(ColumnA) AS ColumnA,ColumnB
            FROM    @T  GROUP BY ColumnB )T
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is optimal, but how about ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07c35/2)):

```
SELECT x.A + COALESCE(SUM(y.A),0) ColumnA, x.ColumnB
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(ColumnA) A, ColumnB
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY ColumnB
) x
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(ColumnA) A, ColumnB
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY ColumnB
) y ON y.ColumnB < x.ColumnB
GROUP BY x.ColumnB, x.A
```

Answer (score 3):

```
create table #T
(
  ID int primary key,
  ColumnA int,
  ColumnB char(1)
);

insert into #T
select row_number() over(order by ColumnB),
       sum(ColumnA) as ColumnA,
       ColumnB
from YourTable
group by ColumnB;

with C as
(
  select ID,
         ColumnA,
         ColumnB
  from #T
  where ID = 1
  union all
  select T.ID,
         T.ColumnA + C.ColumnA,
         T.ColumnB
  from #T as T
    inner join C
      on T.ID = C.ID + 1
)
select ColumnA,
       ColumnB 
from C
option (maxrecursion 0);

drop table #T;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL SERVER? SO

Let think you have a table with 3 column C_1, C_2, C_3 and ordered by C_1.
Simply use [Over (Order By C_1)] to add a column for sum of C_3:

Select C_1, C_2, C_3, Sum(C_3) **Over (Order By C_1)**

if you want row number too, do it in the same way:

Select **Row_Number() Over (Order By C_1),** C_1, C_2, C_3, Sum(C_3) Over (Order By C_1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or greater then this will produce the required result.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
    ColumnA int, 
    ColumnB varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(2,'a'),
(3,'b'),
(4,'c'),
(5,'d'),
(1,'a');

SELECT 
    SUM(ColumnA) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnB ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ColumnA,
    ColumnB
FROM (
    SELECT
        ColumnB,
        SUM(ColumnA) AS ColumnA
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY ColumnB
) DVTBL
ORDER BY ColumnB
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution (simplest and quickest) is to use a `OVER(ORDER BY)` clause.

I will give and explain my problem and the solution found.

I have a table containing some annual transaction that have following columns

```
Yearx    INT
NoSeq    INT
Amount   DECIMAL(10,2)
Balance  DECIMAL(10,2)
```

The first three columns have values; `balance` column is empty.

---

Problem

How to fill `Balance` values considering that first value at 1 January is 5000€ ?

---

Example

```
NoSeq    Amount    Balance
-----  --------  ---------
1       120.00+   5120.00+   <= 5000 + 120     
2        16.00-   5104.00+   <= 5000 + 120 - 16
3      3000.00-   2104.00+   <= 5000 + 120 - 16 + 3000   
4       640.00+   2740.00+   <= 5000 + 120 - 16 + 3000 + 640
```

---

Solution (based on Abdul Rasheed answer)

```
WITH 
t AS
(
SELECT NoSeq
      ,Amount 
  FROM payements
  WHERE Yearx = 2021
)   
SELECT NoSeq
      ,Amount
      ,1179.18 + SUM(Amount) OVER(ORDER BY NoSeq 
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                  AND CURRENT ROW
                                 ) AS Balance
  FROM t
```

In considering that on PostGreSql `ROW BETWEEN` used before is default, previous `SELECT` can be reduced to

```
WITH 
t AS
(
SELECT NoSeq
      ,Amount 
  FROM payements 
  WHERE Yearx = 2021
)   
SELECT NoSeq
      ,Amount
      ,1179.18 + SUM(Amount) OVER(ORDER BY NoSeq) as balance                              
  FROM t
```

The first part (WITH clause) is used to define table on which `OVER(ORDER BY)` is apply in final SELECT.

The second part compute running sum using temporaty `T` table.

In my case, `WITH` clause is not necessary and `SELECT` command can be ultimely reducted to following SQL command

```
SELECT NoSeq
      ,Amount
      ,1179.18 + SUM(Amount) OVER(ORDER BY NoSeq) as balance                              
  FROM payements
  WHERE Yearx = 2021
```

I use this last `SQL` command in my `VB.Net` - `Postgresql` application.

To compute more that one year knowing `Balance` value on 1 January 2010, I use following SQL command

```
SELECT Yearx
      ,NoSeq
      ,Amount
      ,-279.34 + SUM(Amount) OVER(ORDER BY Yearx,NoSeq) as balance                              
  FROM payements
  WHERE Yearx BETWEEN 2010 AND 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ColumnA INT, ColumnB VARCHAR(50));

    INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    (2,           'a'),
    (3  ,         'b'),
    (4   ,        'c'),
    (5    ,       'd'),
    (1     ,      'a');

    ;WITH cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT  ColumnB, sum(ColumnA) value,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnB) sr_no FROM @t group by ColumnB    
    )

    SELECT ColumnB
    ,SUM(value) OVER (   ORDER BY  ColumnB  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND  0  PRECEDING) 
    FROM cte c1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way also:

```
WITH grpAllData
AS
(
   SELECT ColumnB, SUM(ColumnA) grpValue
   FROM table_Name 
   gROUP BY ColumnB

)
SELECT g.ColumnB, sum(grpValue) OVER(ORDER BY ColumnB) desireValue
  FROM grpAllData g
 order by ColumnB
```

In the above query, We first aggregate all values in the same group, then in the final select just applied a window function on the previous result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.columnB as "ColumnB",
SUM(g.group_sum) over (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as "ColumnA" 
FROM (
SELECT SUM(ColumnA) as group_sum,
ColumnB
FROM cand 
GROUP BY ColumnB 
ORDER BY ColumnB) g
```

Grouping ColumnB with SUM aggregation of ColumnA. And then applying window function to ColumnA to generate cumulative sum.

Answer (score 0):

That was my question too and I used answers here. With more research I found another solution which is more **optimized** and **easier**, also more fun! This solutions is based on `Window Functions`.  here it is:

```
--- creating table and inserting values of the question
CREATE TABLE #tmp ( ColumnA INT , ColumnB VARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES (2,'a'),(3,'b'),(4,'c'),(5,'d'),(1,'a')


---- my solution
SELECT  
    SUM(ColumnA) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnB ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) ColumnA 
    ,ColumnB
FROM 
(
    SELECT SUM(ColumnA) ColumnA,ColumnB FROM #tmp GROUP BY ColumnB 
) X
```

And the result is:

```
ColumnA     ColumnB
----------- -------
3           a
6           b
10          c
15          d
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work based on grouping of columns cumulative summation for a column.

See the below SQL

```sql
SELECT     product, 
           product_group, 
           fiscal_year, 
           Sum(quantity) OVER ( partition BY fiscal_year,a.product_group ORDER BY a.posting_date, a.product_group rows 100000000 PRECEDING) AS quantity
FROM       report 
WHERE 
order by   b.fiscal_year DESC
```

Comment: IT  will work based on grouping of columns cumulative summation for a column

Answer (score -2):

You can use below simple select statement for the same

```
SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, 
(SELECT SUM(COLUMN_B) FROM #TBL T2 WHERE T2.ID  <= T1.ID) as SumofPreviousRow FROM #TBL T1;
```